# Understanding LINQ subquery

Tags: c#, list, linq, lambda

I used a normal query inside a `foreach` to reach my goal, but I think there is a better way.

```
int max = 0;
foreach(Area area in myZoo.AreaList)
{
    max = (from a in area.AnimalList
           select a.ID).Max();
}
return max;
```

How can I use a pure LINQ to get the `max` of all sublists? (`Animal` is a `List` of the `class Animal` inside the `AreaList` and contains an `Int32` called `ID`) Erm, and Lambda is welcome, so don't hastitate to answer only because you only know the lambda answer ;)

```
public class Zoo
{
    public List<Area> AreaList {get; set;}
}

public class Area
{
    public List<Animal> AnimalList {get; set;}
}

public class Animal
{
    public List<int> Id {get; set;}
}
```

Only the short form so no one gets confused ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a nested [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549142(v=vs.110).aspx).

`SelectMany` will return a single `IEnumerable<T>` from the many "inner" `Ienumerable<T>` - so `Zoo.SelectMany(a => a.AreaList)` will return a single `IEnumerable<Area>` containing all the `IEnumerable<Area>` from the `Area` property - then you do it one more time for the `List<Animal>` in the `Area` class:

Sample data:

```
var zoo = new Zoo() {
    AreaList = new List<Area>()
    {
        new Area() 
        {
            AnimalList = new List<Animal>()
            {
                new Animal() {Id = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3}},
                new Animal() {Id = new List<int>() {4, 5, 6}}
            }
        },
        new Area() 
        {
            AnimalList = new List<Animal>()
            {
                new Animal() {Id = new List<int>() {7, 8, 9}},
                new Animal() {Id = new List<int>() {10, 11}}
            }
        },
    }
};
```

Linq query:

```
var max = zoo.AreaList.SelectMany(a => a.AnimalList).SelectMany(a => a.Id).Max();

Console.WriteLine(max);
```

Result: 11

In query syntax you can do `SelectMany` by chaining `from` clauses, as shown in gxp's answer. (Personally, I prefer the method chaining syntax, so it took me some time to figure that one out...)

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled  I came up with this `zoo.AreaList.SelectMany(x => x.AnimalList.Select(y => y.Id.Max())).Max();` solution, but as answer is already selected I'm not posting it. But can you explain comparison between your approach and mine.

Comment: It's basiclly a combination between mine and zᴉɹɥƆ's answer - you do a `SelectMany` to flatten one list, then get the a max of the max.

Comment: @ZoharPeled yeah i got to know that by reading all answers (and that's why i didn't answer), and also i read your comment on zᴉɹɥƆ's answer. I'm asking that can this " `SelectMany` to flatten one list, then get the a max of the max" , results beneficial to Space complexity ?

Comment: @Amit I have no idea, and I don't think that matters so much. You should write code for readability. Space complexity shouldn't matter in 2018, unless working in very high-volume data.

Answer (score 3):

Although `SelectMany` works, I feel query is more readable in such case.

```
var max = (from area in myZoo.AreaList
           from animal in area.AnimalList
           from id in animal.Id
           select id).Max();
```

Comment: Thanks. That one I didn't knew (from x in y from a in x.a) was new to me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
var max = zoo.AreaList.Max(arl => arl.AnimalList.Max(anl => anl.Id)).Max();
```

The maximum value of all maximum values of all `AnimalLists`, and the Max of them.

That's effectievly the same as ZoharPeled's `SelectMany`, except he flattens the list and takes the max of all items where I take the max of each list again and again.

Comment: Nice! I wish I would have thought of that one myself :-)